# How to derive the Nautilus Gears equation?

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry

First have a look at some video on Nautilus Gears, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ex_Drh6Rpo. I want to *derive* the formula for this curve, which I know is just the logarithmic/exponential spiral.

I can think of 3 conditions:

1. The sum $r(\theta)+r(\phi)$ should be constant, where $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the corresponding angles over which the gears are rotated.
2. The arc length of the curve between $0$ and $\theta$ should be equal to the arc length of the curve between $\phi$ and $2\pi$ for corresponding $\theta$ and $\phi$.
3. The tangent lines of the two gears should be equal when touching.

It's easy to check that a logarithmic spiral fulfills these 3 conditions, but I want to *derive* the equation as a solution. As commented below, probably many solutions exist, but the above 3 conditions will be common to all. So I'm interested in the general differential equation and solutions, out of which the logarithmic spiral is only one particular solution. What additional constraints give rise to that log-spiral? Note that the "teeth" on the spiral can be neglected.

[image: drawing of nautilus gears]

Sorry for the lousy drawing; I did my best...

Comment: Given the large amount of possible gear shapes, I'd be surprised if your three conditions had only a log spiral as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the relevant equations for non-circular gears in the dedicated [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-circular_gear). Many solutions are possible, as I wrote in my comment above. Here's a simple example of two identical elliptic gears, each rotating around a focus:

[image]

Comment: The wikipedia-article also contains a few additional references I didn't find myself before. Unbelievable I missed this one. Thanks...

Comment: How did you realize this nice animation ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I made it with GeoGebra. I still have the file, I can upload it to GeoGebra site if you want.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca Yes please. As I am a beginner in Geogebra, I will learn from your example. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JeanMarie Here's the link: https://www.geogebra.org/m/t5qrwhqz

Comment: @Intelligenci Pauca Thank you !